# Passing a list from a view to a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, model-view-controller

I'm a relatively new Rails developer with a heavy Java/C# background and I'm trying to pass multiple time ranges from my view to my controller. For instance, the user could select the time range 9:00am to 11:00am as well as 2:00pm to 4:00pm. The first thing to came to mind was a list of times or a list of key value pairs so that I know when a time range starts and ends. I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass this information to my Rails controller though.

Is there an ideal Rails way of passing a list to a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Rails Guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

request
GET /mytime?t[]=1&t[]=2&t[]=3

in view

```
<form method="GET" action="mytime">
<select multiple name="t[]">
<option value="1">1:00pm</option>
<option value="2">2:00pm</option>
<option value="3">3:00pm</option>
</select>
</form>
```

or

```
<form method="GET" action="mytime">
<input type="text" name="t[]">
<input type="hidden" name="t[]" value="11">
</form>


#in mytime_controller.rb
def index
  params[:t] # return Array of values
end
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't occur to me to check the official Rails website.

Answer (score 0):

You pass information from a view to a controller via http query string ('get') or form data ('post').

I would consider multi-select dropdown for this case.

Comment: Well yeah I know you have to use HTTP but how exactly would I access the data over at my controller? Would I have to bruteforce params[datetimeX] (e.g. if params[datetime1] exists, if params[datetime2] exists) or is there some way to get a list type of data structure to access in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropdown i suggest you should create a cool for using some `jquery plugin` that will improve your application's user experience and yes create a rails form and submit it then you can have information in your controller.

Now is you are saving these selected time, that i think you should do then create a model if you haven't already and use `form_for` else your can use `form_tag` for your rails application.

[Visit Here](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/) and find some time picker that suits you need.

Comment: Thanks that was the plan actually. Question though: if I were to submit multiple times as a list how would form_for come into play? Do you have any Rails reading material you would recommend?